# Vue: Update Component data from Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to update data in a component from my Vue instance. Finding plenty of examples on how to do the opposite, but nothing on this.

Say I have:

```
Vue.component('component', {
props: {
    prop: {
        default: null
    }
},
template: '#template',
data: function () {
    return {
        open: false
    };
}
});
```

Now I would like to set `open` to `true` from my Vue instance:

```
var root = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {},
    methods: { updateComponentData: function() {//set open to true} } });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a parent component (`root` in your example) to update a child component (`component` in your example)? If so, it's highly recommended to follow a pattern where **data is passed down from the parent to the child and events are passed up from the child to the parent** ([more in Vue's documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)). In your example, your child would have a `prop` called `open` and your parent would bind the value representing the `open` state to the child component.

Comment: If your component relationship is more complicated than parent-child, you may want to explore patterns revolving around [state management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html).

Comment: The thing is, if you set `open` to be a `prop` you actually get a vue warning telling you it should be data. Either way, as you say I try to pass data from instance (root) to component (component). But they are seperate, so not sure if it counts as parent-child. i.e the component does not exist inside the vue instance. If you think you have a solution please post an answer because I've spent hours in the docs you linked with no real success.

Comment: **"if you set `open` to be a `prop` you actually get a vue warning telling you it should be data"** – would you expand your question to include this attempt? I would not expect Vue attempting to warn you regarding this.

Comment: **"I try to pass data from instance (root) to component (component). But they are seperate, so not sure if it counts as parent-child. i.e the component does not exist inside the vue instance."** – not too sure what you mean by this, you could expand your question to include an example more representative of your component hierarchy. A _parent-child_ relationship between components is where the child is a direct descendent of the parent; in the parent's template, it could look something like this: `<div>...<child-component>...</child-component>...</div>`.

Comment: Thanks, `root` is not a component. i.e `component` is not a child of `root`. `root` is a Vue instance. these are not the same things.

Comment: **"`root` is not a component. i.e `component` is not a child of `root`"** – I'm going to make the assumption that `component` is a (non-direct) descendent of `root`. Based on that, the options are: passing data via props down the component tree from the `root` to the `component` – this may not be ideal if there are a few descendent components between the `root` and the `component`; using [state management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html); or moving the source of the data away from `root` to the component that is the parent of `component`. I may expand on this in an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a [Child Component Ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="template" ref="component">
    <div>Hello, {{ name }}!</div>
</script>
```

```js
var root = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {},
  methods: { 
    updateComponentData: function() {
      this.$refs.component.open = true
    } 
  } 
});
```

---

**Working example**

```js
const Child = Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Component1</h2>
      <div>Hello, {{ title }}! <strong>{{ open }}<strong></div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'component',
      open: false
    }
  }
});

var root = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Child
  },
  methods: { 
    updateComponentData: function() {
      //console.log('updateComponentData', this.$refs)
      this.$refs.component1.open = true
    } 
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Parent</h2>
  <button v-on:click="updateComponentData">Click me true</button>
  <child ref="component1"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: It's Vue, see link to docs above, they use `root.$refs.component` outside the parent, so I assumed `this.$refs.component` inside. I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can tell it does not work. I think because we are setting the ref inside a component, not the Vue Instance. So when we say this.$refs it does not find the ref we are talking about, because it is not in the instance itself

Comment: You're correct, the ref goes on the parent template. I've got a working sample now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your example but adding `components` to my instance leads to entire page not compiling properly. Ill keep trying maybe im missing something

Answer (score 1):

I just played with your code and the following codes works perfect please do try that. I have used Vue 'ref'. Add `ref` attribute in your component and then you can access that specific components data from parent.

```js
Vue.component('component', {
    props: {
        prop: {
            default: null
        }
    },
    template: '#template',
    data: () => ({
        open: false
    })
});
var root = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: () => ({}),
    methods: {
        updateComponentData: function() {
         this.$refs.myComponent.open = true
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="root">
   <button @click="updateComponentData">Change</button>
    <hr>
    <component ref='myComponent'></component>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template" ref="component">
    <div>Open: {{ open }}!</div>
</script>
```