# How I found the value of the element V-model binding in Vue3 through the Dom object of the form element and modified it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm writing a plug-in based on Vue 3, and now I need a feature that is obviously not part of the Vue 3 API, and I think that requires some knowledge of the Vue 3 source code to do that, here is a description of the required functionality:

Suppose you have the following code snippet：

```html
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" v-model="state.text">
</div>

<script>
    const {createApp, reactive} = Vue
    const vm = createApp({
        setup ()
        {
            const state = reactive({
                text: "123"
            })

            return {
                state
            }
        }
    }).mount(".box")
</script>
```

Based on this code snippet, I need to modify the v-model value outside of Vue through the dom object of the input element. How can I do this?

```js
const input_dom = document.querySelector("input")

// I have obtained the input_dom, and I hope to change the value of state.text through input_dom.

input_dom??
```

Comment: you have to use pinia or vuex to store the data in state. On update the value you also need to update the state. check here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

Comment: @sandipbharadva This seems irrelevant to the question

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281746/vue-update-component-data-from-vue-instance

Comment: This is XY problem, consider reasking the question and explaining the actual case. Vue doesn't do that. There may be internal properties like element.__vnode but they aren't documented and may not be supported in prod. If you have a demand to interact with the outside world, Vue app should have public api to support that, or possibly stick to web components instead of monolith app

Answer (score 0):

There are undocumented  `__vue_app__`, etc properties in Vue 3 but they are intended for debugging and may not be available in production build.

A good practice is to explicitly expose public API. If changing field value is expected, doing this with a method would be easier to debug and maintain.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(el => {
  const app = createApp({
    setup (props, ctx) {
      ...
      ctx.expose({
        update(val) {
          state.text = val;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  el.myApp = app.mount(el);
});
```

And used like:

```
document.querySelector(".box").myApp.change(...);
```

For single app instance it can be global variable as it's easier to track and debug:

```
window.myApp = app.mount("#box")
```